# Get unique value by grouped row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series like this before doing groupby('A') and want to see the difference of composition among these groups:

```
    A    B    C
1  us   air   35
2  us   gas   34
3  us   sun   30
4  us   fog   23
5  us   mud   33
6  fr   air   45
7  fr   bug   15
8  fr   sun   35
9  fr   mud   85
      ...
```

Could anyone please help me with how to see the variance of groups?
Something I need would be like:

```
us    [air,gas,sun,fog,mud]
eu    [air,gas,sun,fog]
fr    [air,bug,sun,mud]
```

Thank you very much and I greatly appreciate your help.

--update

[data is here](https://t.ly/7vKy)

I would like to see if every day has the same composition.
It doesn't work well when I tried `groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].unique()`

Thanks in advance.

--update

Thanks to @Perl. `df.groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].apply(list)` works. But it's not what I want. What I want is to get a unique combination in a day(like set). Similar to use set(['ItemEngName'] after groupby.

So I tried `df.groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].unique()` and got

```
MonitorDate 
2010/1/1    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/2    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/3    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/4    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/5    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/6    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
2010/1/7    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...
Name:     ItemEngName, dtype: object
```

It seems they are all the same except 1/7.
But I need to check the difference manually.

--update

Expected Output:

Thanks @perl again

```
MonitorDate 
2010/1/1    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ..., WS_HR]
2010/1/7    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...]
Name:     ItemEngName, dtype: object
```

For more data case, the more complicated condition would be like:

```
MonitorDate 
2010/1/1    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ..., WS_HR] (full)
2010/1/7    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ...] ..(lack WS_HR)
2010/1/8    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM2.5, ..., WS_HR] .(lack PM10)
2010/1/9    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, , ...] .......(lack PM2.5)
...
Name:     ItemEngName, dtype: object
```

I can only use `df.groupby('MonitorDate')["ItemEngName"].nunique().unique()`to know different number of items but not knowing the difference of components.
Is there any effective way?

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` column A, then take the B column and convert grouped values to lists with `apply`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
A
fr         [air, bug, sun, mud]
us    [air, gas, sun, fog, mud]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

If the lists may have duplicates and you're only interested in unique values, probably the best option is to go with the solution from @anky's comment:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].unique()
```

---

**Update:** In your dataset they are almost the same, except `2010/1/7` not having `WS_HR`:

```
df[['MonitorDate', 'ItemEngName']].value_counts().unstack()
```

Output:

```
ItemEngName  AMB_TEMP   CO   NO  NO2  NOx   O3  PM10  PM2.5   RH  SO2  WD_HR  \
MonitorDate                                                                    
2010/1/1          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/2          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/3          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/4          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/5          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/6          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   
2010/1/7          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0   

ItemEngName  WIND_DIREC  WIND_SPEED  WS_HR  
MonitorDate                                 
2010/1/1            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/2            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/3            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/4            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/5            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/6            1.0         1.0    1.0  
2010/1/7            1.0         1.0    NaN
```

---

**Update 2:** If you just want to visually check which days have which items, you can plot it. Here for example you can see that `WS_HR` is missing on `2010/1/7`:

```
z = df[['MonitorDate', 'ItemEngName']].value_counts().unstack()
plt.pcolor(z, alpha=0.2)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(z.index), 1), z.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(z.columns), 1), z.columns, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: picture]

Comment: `set` would be better than `list` as it would remove duplicates

Comment: @PaulH I thought about it too, but expected output looks like a list (square brackets). So if it's needed to get unique values, I would probably go with the `.unique()` option that @anky posted as a comment

Comment: @perl Hi, thanks, I've followed your instruction but got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @WayneHwang Hi, can you post the data that leads to this error? It's not a problem with the sample that you provided above

Comment: @perl
Hi, here it is: 
t.ly/7vKy
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @WayneHwang Worked for me with `df.groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].apply(list)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Perl Yes, it works. The TypeError previously was from `df.groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].apply(list).unique()`

And still it's not what I want. What I want is to get a unique combination in a day. So I tried `df.groupby('MonitorDate')['ItemEngName'].unique()` and got 
(Something I updated above)
    MonitorDate
    2010/1/1    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ... ... 
    2010/1/6    [AMB_TEMP, CO, NO, NO2, NOx, O3, PM10, PM2.5, ... 
    Name: ItemEngName, dtype: object 


It seems they are all the same.

Comment: Well they are almost the same because they are almost the same in the dataset that you provided. The only difference is `2010/1/7` not having the `WS_HR` value. Please see the update in my answer

Comment: Yes, thanks again!
So in this case I expect the result would return two kinds of the list ( if indicates which day is better).
Like your answer first time:
fr         [air, bug, sun, mud]
us    [air, gas, sun, fog, mud]

Instead of one list a day and there are seven when I use `.unique()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you please post what is exactly the expected output from your dataset?

Comment: @perl Sorry for the poor explanation.
I just saw your update and tried.
It shows `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Another issue is when the data is more than 7 days and has more combination of ItemEngName, it seems hard to tell how many kinds of ItemEngName sets are in this way. Still appreciate a lot!

Comment: Sure, still not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to visually understand which days have which combinations, I would plot it, see update 2 in my answer for an example. Regarding that error, could it be that you're using an older version of `pandas`? `DataFrame.value_counts` was added in 1.1.0